# How to find layout_marginTop

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an XML file with the following attritubes:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/al_cs_layout1"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/cs_track" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/fader_background5"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
</ImageView>
...
```

and here is my java code:

```
public void initialize(Context context)
{
Log.d("initialize (MySeekBar)","initialize");
setWillNotDraw(false);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_seekbar, this);

layout1 = (RelativeLayout)view1.findViewById(R.id.al_cs_layout1);
track = (ImageView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.cs_track);
thumb = (ImageView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.cs_thumb);
...
```

I am working on a custom seekbar which determines the top by using a variable marginTop = 20; however this was oringally made on a phone much older by a different programmer. The 20 suppose to represent the margin top defined in the XML however it is using dp and not pixels. how can I find the marginTop attribute of R.id.cs_track? It works great on the old phone but on any phone does doesn't have the same screen size of dp it will create an undesired offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MarginLayoutParams to get value in pixels:

```
track = (ImageView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.cs_track);
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams)track.getLayoutParams();
int marginTopPixelSize = params.topMargin;
```

Comment: thank you. I tried something similar but for some reason it wasn't working. It appears to be working fine now.